# Flutter Dio doesn't accept int value as queryParameters

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm making  a call using Dio that send some query parameters, using map constructor

```
  response = await Dio().get(url, queryParameters: {
    "apikey": publicKey,
    "hash": hash,
    "ts": timestamp,
    "nameStartsWith": searchTerm
  });
```

Everything works correctly, but when try to send a int value, Dio throw a error

```
  response = await Dio().get(url, queryParameters: {
    "apikey": publicKey,
    "hash": hash,
    "ts": timestamp,
    "nameStartsWith": searchTerm,
    "page" : 10
  });
```

> type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'Iterable < dynamic > '#0

And i can't just convert the int value to string, because api is expcting int type.

Any help ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no such thing as an int type in an URL and therefore in query parameters.
An URL can only be a String.

Just convert it to String and be done.

Comment: When I convert to String, apparently dio send it with quotation marks and the api doesn't recognize  the value

Comment: The first example in https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/dio#examples also passes an integer value as string. Either your code does something wrong or it's a bug in DIO

Comment: Actually, i tried again converting to string and  worked as expected.  I think i was passing wrong parameter.. thanks !